# How to get top 5 highest score in Firebase Database Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the top 5 highest points in firebase database. I am new to firebase and I am using it with Unity. Here is the structure of my Firebase Database.

```
users{
  user1:{
    email: 'user1@email.com',
    points: '5'
  },
  user2:{
    email: 'user2@email.com',
    points: '3'
  },
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't have many expirience with Firebase, but, I could advise you to use methods `OrderByValue()` and `LimitToFirst()`
There is you can find more about sorting and filtering data in Firebase Realtime DB:
[link to firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Answer (score 0):

hi just in case someone like me bumps into this problem.

```
using System.Linq;
public static void Initialize()
{
    database.GetReference(LEADERBOARDS).OrderByChild("score")
    .LimitToLast(100).ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

static void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    IEnumerable<DataSnapshot> snapshots = new List<DataSnapshot>(args.Snapshot.Children).Reverse<DataSnapshot>();
    foreach(var child in snapshots)
    {
         var json = child.GetRawJsonValue();
         HighScore hs = JsonUtility.FromJson<HighScore>(json);
         Debug.Log(hs.displayName + "_" + hs.score);
    }
}
```